# Do Documentation views affect your Impact?

Tags: discussion, documentation, people-reached

Do Documentation views affect your Impact number (the number of people reached)?

And as Jon Adams commented The documentation may be built-up by any number of users? Does a single view up the Impact for all participating parties in an example?

Comment: And if so, who? The documentation may be built-up by any number of users? Does a single view up the Impact for all participating parties in an example?

Comment: And if so, would a topic view count to your Impact if you only contributed one example that wasn't even viewed that time?

Comment: I strongly doubt they do right now, but I also wonder if they'd ever bother calculating it since it's such a different system of views.

Answer (score -3):

I have thousands of up-votes on documentation and my impact did not move at all. It was, and is still, around 7 000.

Therefore, the documentation does not seem to affect your Impact.

Still, it **should** affect your impact, as it clearly helps/impacts others.

PS: I only did some edits and added informations or removed things from the doc, I did not create a post from scratch, so it's possible it affects Impact but only for the original writer? Not sure about this.

Comment: Why the downvotes?